# Why style a lists

Tags: html, css, list

What is the point in styling a ul? I Have a following html structure

```
<div id='container'>
<div id='ui' class='quad'>
    <div class='quadNav'>
        <span class='quadTitle'>Urgent And Important</span>
        <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x addButton"></i>
    </div>
    <ul class='taskList'>
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the following css for styling the list

```
.taskList{

}
.taskList li{
  list-style-type:none;
  position:relative;
  top:2em;
  left:1.2em;

}
```

with the .taskList section empty the li elements will style as I want them to. But if I remove the .taskList section, the li's no longer style. What gives? What is supposed to go into the styling of a ul element vs a li element, I don't understand.

edit
I may not have properly worded my question, I have the following css

```
<style>
    /* -------- General Styling ---------*/
    *{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    html, body {
        font-size:20px;
    }

    #container{
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
    }

    /*--------Quadrant Style ------- */
    .quad{
        position: relative;
        width: 49.85%;
        height: 49.8%;
        font-size: .8em;
        border: solid 1px black;
    }

    #ui{
        float: left;
        background-color: green;
    }

    #nui{
        float: right;
        background-color: red;
    }

    #uni{
        float: left;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    #nuni{
        float:right;
        background-color:yellow;
    }


      /*------- Quadrant Navigation Styling ------- */
.quadNav{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  top:1em;
}
.quadTitle{
  position: relative;
  left:1em;
}
.addButton{
  position:relative;
  float:right;
  right: 1em;
}
/*---------- task list styling ----------*/'
.taskList{

}
.taskList li{
  list-style-type:none;
  position:relative;
  top:2em;
  left:1.2em;

}
```

When I remove the empty .taskList{} declaration the .tasklist li styles stop working. I am trying to figure out why.

Comment: ***if I remove the .taskList section*** then of course all the selectors in the rules in the CSS code are useless. the `li` elements are not tracked to to style.

Comment: if i remove the .taskList{}?

Comment: I don't think people are understanding your question. My guess is there's something before the .taskList{} in your CSS that e.g. has an error. The .taskList {} is getting caught up in that error, but that doesn't matter because it's not doing anything. When you remove it, you're now getting your .taskList li mixed up with the preceding CSS. Try posting the preceding CSS in your question - it may help clarify.

Comment: you have an apostrophe after your comment - remove it and the .taskList { } and it will be fine - I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you. I will now go hide in shame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could happen if you have an error in the preceding CSS, e.g.

```
.broken {
    something
/* note no closing brace */

.taskList{

}
.taskList li{
  list-style-type:none;
  position:relative;
  top:2em;
  left:1.2em;
}
```

Now, the `.taskList {` line is actually inside the `.broken {...} block`, and the closing brace for `.taskList` closes that, so the following `.taskList li {` block works ok. But if you remove the `.taskList` block, you now wind up with the `.taskList li` styling inside the erroneous block, and your styling stops working.

EDIT: in your updated code, I can see the problem is a stray apostrophe on the line

```
/*---------- task list styling ----------*/'
```

Remove the trailing `'` and it will fix it

Answer (score 1):

the reason you lose the styling when you take out the `taskList` is because in your CSS you are targeting any `li` that is a child of a class called `taskList`. The reason you should do this is if you choose to have another set of `li`'s on the page or any other page that may share this stylesheet you can style them differently by targeting a different class name. As far as the `ul` goes, if you do not use normalize or a css reset, `ul`'s indent naturally without having to style it that way.

Comment: I think OP means removing the empty css declaration, not the nodes - how that's possible, IDK, but... yea

Comment: Yes, if I remove the .taskList{ } from the stylesheet the .taskList li{} style no longer works. That's what I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

The `li` styling you currently have is applied only to the sub elements of the `.taskList` class.

If you want it to apply to all `li`'s change your css to this:

```
li{
  list-style-type:none;
  position:relative;
  top:2em;
  left:1.2em;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
.taskList li{
    list-style-type:none;
    position:relative;
    top:2em;
    left:1.2em;
}
```

So you are able to select `li`s in the `ul` with class of `taskList` and that's why style will be applied on those `li`s but if you remove the class `taskList` from the `ul` then the style won't be applied in the `li`s inside the `ul` with class `taskList` because you didn't add styles to `li`s directly.

If you want to style `li`s in any place of your page then you may use something like this:

```
li {
    /*rules*/
}
```

Also to apply styles on all `li`s inside `ul` with class `taskList` you don't need to add a blank selection like you did in your question which is:

```
.taskList {

}
```

This is unnecessary in this case. You can apply stiles on all of your `li`s inside `ul` with class `taskList` even without the blank `.taskList{...}` in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the comment line right before `.taskList{}`, here you see:

[image]

Then when you keep the `.taskList{}`, that rule will be seen as invalid, while the next rules are OK, if removing that rule, then the rule `.taskList li{}` will be invalid, hence your problem.

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/V3Wcw/6/)